# 3D Object doesnt renders poorly but superb in Online Viewer for GLTF-Files

Tags: html, three.js, blender, gltf

I want to display a model created in Blender ([image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpE9Z.png)) and showcase it on a webpage. However, the rendered quality appears to be poor, specifically with the edges not being rendered properly ([image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpE9Z.png)). Conversely, when viewing the model in an online viewer, the edges appear smooth and rendered properly ([image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogSx9.jpg)).

Here's the code I'm using:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app Yeah Yeah</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="three.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import { GLTFLoader } from './GLTFLoader.js';

    let scene = new THREE.Scene();
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    let loader = new GLTFLoader();

    let obj;
    loader.load("schrankd.gltf", function (gltf) {
        obj = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    let light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 3);
    scene.add(light);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, 5);

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set anti aliasing on `true`:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
});
```

and pixel ratio

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
```

Comment: Wow this solved it! thanks  know i just have to add light to the camera point and i am good to go!